# PHP img src not being echo

Tags: php

I have a folder with te following path /xampp/htdocs/pic  ,which has got some images.

I am using the following code to echo the images.But the images are not showing.
Not sure where I am making the mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN”
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml” xml:lang=”en” lang=”en”>
<head>
<title>Listing the contents of a directory</title>
<link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”common.css” />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Listing the contents of a directory</h1>
<?php
   $dir = opendir("/xampp/htdocs/pic");
   while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {



echo '<img src="<?php echo "/xampp/htdocs/pic/".$file."</br>";?>"/>';

   }
   closedir($dir);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo "<img src='/xampp/htdocs/pic/$file'/>";`

Comment: If the path you are trying to get the image is correct, below code should work.
Change `echo '<img src="<?php echo "/xampp/htdocs/pic/".$file."</br>";?>"/>';` to `echo '<img src="/xampp/htdocs/pic/'.$file.'"/>';`

Comment: To expand on @Fky's comment, unlike JavaScript the *type* of quote mark matters in PHP - see: [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in the manual. However, I'd guess your docroot is `/xampp/htdocs/` so `echo "<img src='/pic/$file'/>";` would be more likely to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is just generating the HTML document and than sending it to the client. The source resolution of the image will be handled by the client`s browser. Therefore, you have to reference your public folder like so:

`src="./pic/$file"`

Also, you have an error in your HTML. A void/empty element cannot contain another element. Therefore, you have to edit your echo string and remove the `<br/>`:

`echo "<img src='./pic/$file' />";`

This is a little bit on top but every [HTML image element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) should also contain an alternate text attribute to describe the picture like so:

`echo "<img src='./pic/$file' alt='my image title' />";`